# Discord slash commands not responding within 3 seconds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@tree.command(name = "example_command", description = "Example")
async def example_command(interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    try:
        file = test_function() # Takes a couple of seconds to run
        d_file = discord.File('nba_ev.png')
        await interaction.followup.send(file=d_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        error_message = "An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again."
        await interaction.followup.send(content=error_message, ephemeral=True)
```

I have a discord slash command in python `example_command` it calls a function `test_function()` that takes a few seconds to run.

The issue is when another user tries to use the `example_command` or a different slash command but `test_function` is still running I get an error "The application did not respond" I assume it is because `await interaction.response.defer()` did not get called within 3 seconds because `test_function` from the previous invocation is still running

How can I stop this from occurring? I am currently hosting this on GCP Compute Engine

Comment: You can try and make the `test_function()` asynchronous.
instead of `def` use `async def` and when calling the function use `await test_function()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs because your `test_function()` function is fully synchronous. This way, after your machine's processor enters this function, it will only leave when it is completely completed, making it impossible to execute other commands in parallel.

To work around this, you can try implementing threads or converting your synchronous `test_function` function to an asynchronous function.

When trying to make it an asynchronous function, you can first eliminate bad practices, such as replacing `time.sleep()` with `await asyncio.sleep()` and using `aiohttp` instead of `requests`. Don't forget to define the function as asynchronous using `async def`.